# mysql_connect() on localhost

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache

I am trying to implement a little 'intranet' on my home network, but I am an apache/mysql configuration noob...

Running fedora 10, and have apache, mysql, and php set up as well as i know how.  However, when I try using a standard form with POST, the php script seems to error out on the mysql_connect(...); line.  I don't get an error message, in fact the browser page is blank, even in the view source window.  Here is what I have:

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost:1186", "user", "password");

...
```

I have added the username and password in the mysqladmin tool, and i've tried "localhost" and "localhost:1186", as I saw the 1186 port referenced in my my.cnf file.

Obviously I have something configured wrong, any ideas?

Comment: any chance you could post the error message you are getting . that might be more useful than 'seems to error out'

Comment: Like I said, there was no error message, turns out I never installed the php-mysql package

Comment: oops missed that . sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resulting page is blank when there's an error. One of the more common errors to make in your setup is to forget to install either the php-mysql or mysql-server packages. Verify that they're installed, and if not install either or both and then restart the httpd service, and start the mysql service if not running.

Answer (score 0):

the default for a fresh mysql install would be

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost:3306", "root", "");

or just

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

This is good for testing purposes but leaving the root account unprotected is a bad habit.